# How to sort others row depends on a particular row in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

In my worksheet, there are three columns. I want to sort other values based on Point. Here is the cell values.

```
Name      Date     Point

Bela     3/2/12      19
John     1/4/16      32
Reba     9/1/10      21
Risala   3/31/13     21
```

I want to sort like the following. If same point found, then it will be sorted based on Date. How can I do this in VBA?

```
Name      Date     Point

John     1/4/16      32
Risala   3/31/13     21
Reba     9/1/10      21
Bela     3/2/12      19
```

Here is the code of point calculation.

```
Private Sub Sum_Click()
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows,    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Range("C6:C" & LastRow).Formula = "=DateDif(B6, Today(),""y"")+8"

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot use the built in sort functionality in Excel?

Comment: start recording a macro, do your sorting and stop the macro. you'll get a good starting code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your data as shown in image and run below line of code.

[image]

```
 Range("A1").Sort key1:=Range("E1"), order1:=xlDescending, key2:=Range("F1"), order2:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes

 Range("A1").Sort key1:=Range("C1"), order1:=xlDescending, key2:=Range("B1"), order3:=xlDescending, key4:=Range("D1"), order2:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
```

Comment: I guess you have to change those `"I1"` and `"G1"` address to match your linked image data structure...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have another question. Here I can sort date if points are same but if there is two date fields, how can I handle this? Suppose date1, date 2 and Point. If points are same, date1 will be sorted. But if Points and date1 is same, then how can I sort that point depends on date2? Can you help me for doing this? @AdityaPansare

Comment: Add third level by like this.... say you have date2 in col D then..... Range("A1").Sort key1:=Range("C1"), order1:=xlDescending, key2:=Range("B1"), order2:=xlDescending,  key3:=Range("D1"), order3:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes

Comment: I did this. But faced a problem while adding key4. It showed "Named argument not found". How to sort more than 3 columns?

Comment: VBA sort feature only allows to nominate up to 3 columns to sort by.... you can simply sort the data one time with different columns. I.e. to different sorts on same data.

Comment: So, how can I handle key 4 like this way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126394/discussion-between-aditya-pansare-and-tanzilamohita).